# How to show alerts in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, alert, tkmessagebox

I want to show alerts in `tkinter` in python.
Is there anyone who can tell me how to show alerts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tkinter.messagebox` to create a pop up that display an information, warning, or error

like:

```
tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title = "Ooops",message = "Please choose another file")
```

More here:

[tkinter.messagebox (Python 3 documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html) 
[Standard Dialogs (effbot tkinterbook)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201121191823id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

add this code:

```
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
```

if you want to show an error use this:

```
mb.showerror(title = "", message = "")
```

but if you want to show a warning use this:

```
mb.showwarning(title = "", message = "")
```